# Pass two different DirSets in Ant in a custom task

Tags: ant

How can I pass two different DirSets in Ant in a custom task.

Use case: I need two different lists of directories passed into the task.

```
<target name="name123">
    <customTask> 
        <dirset id="sourceDirs" .../> 
        <dirset id="classesDirs" .../>
    </customTask>
</target>
```

the custom task needs to have two different array lists with dirs

Comment: Expand on your question, show some code perhaps.

Comment: <target name="name123">
    <customTask>
        <dirset id="sourceDirs" .../>
        <dirset id="classesDirs" .../>
    </customTask>
</target>

the custom task needs to have two different array lists with dirs

Comment: You should edit your question